# Using CSS to adjust placement of PlaceBarActions in xPages Ext Lib Application Layout Control

Tags: css, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the Notes 9 extension library application layout control and I would like to use CSS to float the place bar actions on the left instead of the right.

Those actions are styled with the `lotusBtnContainer` class using a `float:right` property. How do I override that class with my own class that uses a `float:left`?

I can make the adjustment to the `lotusBtnContainer` class in firebug but I don't want to touch that class for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: cascading. If your stylesheet is below the stylesheet that defines lotusBtnContainer, then it will override the styles above it. You should be able to add a stylesheet to the page that contains the same definition. One caveat is that you must match the specificity of the lotusBtnContainer definition in the theme stylesheet. If the css definition is td.lotusBtnContainer then in order to override you must also use td.lotusBtnContainer, not just .lotusBtnContainer.

If you need any additional help with this, please add the definition of the lotusBtnContainer from the default css files and I can assist further.

Edit: Additionally, if this doesn't work, adding the class with the style you want like this should override:

```
.lotusBtnContainer{float:left !important;}
```